# How can i run a loop "n" number of times regardless of user input?

Tags: java, loops

So i want my program to run through a loop exactly 40 times regardless of user input.

```
for (int number = input.nextInt(); number < 40; number ++)
```

if the user enters 0, the program will run 40 times and out put 1 to 40 but, if they put 30 then the program will run 10 times and out put values from 30 to 40.

How can i have the user enter 30, or any other value and still have the program run 40 times to 70, or what ever.

Comment: Variable `i` is undefined in your example. Is `number` supposed to be `i`?

Comment: Sorry yes it is

Comment: Just ignore the user input.

Comment: Scary Wombat's answer should suffice your needs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

just have a normal for loop

```
int number = input.nextInt();  // or should this be in the loop?
for (int i = 0; i < 40; i++) {
    System.out.println (String.valueOf  (number + i));  
}
```

Comment: How would it look if i wanted it in the loop?

Comment: Why would you put it **in** the loop?  From the compilers point of view, it is doing exactly the same thing, but it is more readable

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int number = input.nextInt(); i < 40+number; i++)
```